# JavaScript infinity loop while generation numbers with minus?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have JavaScript code that is used to make math problems(simple math questions). Everything is randomized.
With plus(+) everything works fine.
e.x.

1+3

2+4

8+9

### The problem:

When the function that check if the first number for minus parameter is greater that the second(1-2 false;2-1 code executes) an infinity loop happens. I'm not good with the explanations hope will will get it when you see the code.

**The structure of the output is:**

the numbers from 1-10(random) with plus

the numbers from 1-10(random) with minus

the numbers from 1-100(random) with plus

the numbers from 1-10(random) with minus

```
<html>
    <p id='plus10'></p>
    <p id='minus10'></p>
    <p id='plus100'></p>
    <p id='minus100'></p>

    <script>
     arr2 = [];
     var lastArr2 = [];
    var num1,num2;   
//FIRST ARRAY 
    while(lastArr2.length<121){
        arr2.push('<br>'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'+'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'=');
    lastArr2=removeDuplicates(arr2);

    }

    document.getElementById('plus10').innerHTML=(lastArr2.join(' '));




    //SECOND ARRAY



    arr1 = [];
    var lastArr1 = [];

    while (lastArr1.length < 121) {
      arr1.push('<br>' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '+' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '=');
      lastArr1 = removeDuplicates(arr1);
    }

    document.getElementById('plus100').innerHTML = (lastArr1.join(' '));



    //THIRD ARRAY



    arr3 = [];
    var lastArr3 = [];

    while (lastArr3.length < 121) {
    gen();

    }



    function gen(){
    //minus function
    num1=Math.round(Math.random()*10);
    num2=Math.round(Math.random()*10);

    if(num1<num2){
    gen();
    }else{
    lastArr3 = removeDuplicates(arr3);
    arr1.push(num1+'-'+num2+'=');
    }

    }




    document.getElementById('minus10').innerHTML = (lastArr3.join(' '));











    function removeDuplicates(arr){
        let unique_array = []
        for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
            if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
                unique_array.push(arr[i])
            }
        }
        return unique_array
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

### **EDIT:**

I was wrong about

```
 arr1.push(num1+'-'+num2+'=');
```

It should be

```
arr3.push(num1+'-'+num2+'=');
```

**But this doesn't fix the infinity loop**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but your

```
while (lastArr3.length < 121) {
    gen();
}
```

`while` here (for the third array) definitely seems like a infinite loop to me. You should make some changes to your `lastArr3` inside `gen()` to make your condition `lastArr3.length < 121` unmet, which will finally break you out of the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `gen()` function, `arr1.push()` should probably be `arr3.push()`, otherwise the looping condition will never change and it will stay in infinite loop.