# JavaScript infinity loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm making JavaScript algorithm that generates simple math questions(problems) with all possible combination in random order.

e.x.

1+2

3+5

7+2

3+1

The working combination is with plus numbers. The problem is when i try to generate the numbers with minus. The algorithm should generate the first number bigger than the second

e.x.

firstNumber(bigger)-secondNumber(lower)

5-3

4-1

2-5(not possible)

Anyway the code execute infinity loop that i can't figure it out. Please provide help with working example. If you have any questions write in the comment section. Thanks for any help:)

```
<html>
    <p id='plus10'></p>
    <p id='minus10'></p>
    <p id='plus100'></p>
    <p id='minus100'></p>

    <script>
        arr2 = [];
        var lastArr2 = [];
        var num1, num2;

        while(lastArr2.length < 121) {
            arr2.push('<br>' + Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + '+' + Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + '=');
            lastArr2 = removeDuplicates(arr2);
        }

        document.getElementById('plus10').innerHTML = (lastArr2.join(' '));

        arr1 = [];
        var lastArr1 = [];

        while(lastArr1.length < 121) {
            arr1.push('<br>' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '+' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '=');
            lastArr1 = removeDuplicates(arr1);
        }

        document.getElementById('plus100').innerHTML = (lastArr1.join(' '));

        arr3 = [];
        var lastArr3 = [];

        while(lastArr3.length < 121) {
            gen();
        }

        function gen() {
            //minus function
            num1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            num2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

            if(num1 < num2) {
                gen();
            } else {
                lastArr3 = removeDuplicates(arr3);
                arr3.push(num1 + '-' + num2 + '=');
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('minus10').innerHTML = (lastArr3.join(' '));

        function removeDuplicates(arr) {
            let unique_array = []
            for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
                    unique_array.push(arr[i])
                }
            }
            return unique_array
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't you post this exact question a day or so ago?

Comment: why not generate two values and add the values for the bigger one and take one of the random values for subtraction.

Comment: Not the same. I fixed a bug, but the code still don't work. When i asked the question before i didn't get solution that work.

Comment: Please try removing all the unnecessary whitespace so people don't have to needlessly scroll through your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript infinity loop while generation numbers with minus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826671/javascript-infinity-loop-while-generation-numbers-with-minus)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your while loop for the minus combinations for numbers 0-10.

```
while (lastArr3.length < 121) {
  gen();
}
```

The problem here is that there are not 121 combinations so lastArr3.length will never be 121. With the plus combinations, this works because there are exactly 121 combinations of 2 numbers between 0 and 10. However, now that you've eliminated every combination where the first number is less than the second number, the number of combinations goes down.

With that said, may I suggest a more effective way of achieving what you're trying to do? By using Math.random() to generate your numbers you'll get a lot of inconsistency with how long it takes the loop to run. How about generating all the combinations in order and then inserting them into the array randomly instead?

Something like this:

```
var arr = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
  for (var k = i; k <= 10; ++k) {
    var str = '<br>' + k + '-' + i + '='
    var index = Math.round(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))
    arr.splice(index, 0, str)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing values only when num1>num2, you can do it even when num1 < num2.

```
if(num1 < num2){
    arr3.push(num2 + '-' + num1 + '=' );
}
```